# How to restrict Google API Key for Hybrid app?

Tags: firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm building a production hybrid mobile app that uses Firebase/Firestore. Since it's a hybrid app, I can not use the bundle ID or HTTP referrer methods to restrict the API key (Google support confirmed this is not supported).

My worry is that anyone could decompile the app and get the API key, using it with a simple Node.js script locally, and access my database.

Node.js scripts can bypass all Firestore rules, making unrestricted API keys very powerful. So far I have been unable to find a way to restrict keys with hybrid apps, including reaching out to Google support. I'm wondering if the only way to actually achieve firebase/firestore security is to use Native apps vs. Hybrid?

Comment: Use environment.ts with production enable and keep your keys inside that file.

Comment: This is not relevant to my question. I'm talking about restricting API keys through the Google Console.

Answer (score 0):

Actually for ios, we are not able to restrict the google api key. But, for android we have done with  HTTP referrer method only.

For android it is possible.

If you are using ionic4, Please use the same origin value whatever you set in you config.xml corresponding to you android app.